# How to remove the broken part of the tip inside of the stylus of Sony Digital Paper DPT-RP1?

Tags: technology, hardware

I have a Sony's Digital Paper [DPT-RP1](https://www.sony.com/electronics/digital-paper-notepads/dpt-rp1) and it's great. Unfortunately, Its stylus tip seems to be prone to breaking in halves, as documented in multiple forum posts, as well as the multiple answers to this question.

Broken tip:

[image: Broken tip]

Normal tip:

[image: Normal tip]

When the break happened, the first part of the tip got totally stuck within the stylus (there is a kind of latch mechanism to hold it in place) and I couldn't get it out.

[image: Stylus]

The distance from the outside of the stylus to the broken part is about 2cm.

I tried to use a needle to nudge it out to no avail. I guess it's tightly snatched in place by the mechanism around, and it's really long.

Is there any way to get it out?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it would work if you heat a thin needle to the point where it melts the plastic the tip is made of, stick it into the stuck part, wait till it cools and solidifies, then pull the needle? Could check first on the other part of the broken tip to see if it would work on that kind of plastic. Or use a really thin drill to drill a hole in the center, put a slightly thicker screw into it, pull.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

My pencil dropped down and broke for months and I've fixed it just now.

Here're some tips share with you, hope it helps if you encountered with 
the same problem.

Prepare a needle,  as **thin** as possible, heat top point with lighter,
util it turning red, then quickly jag the needle into the plastic pin, 
slightly push the needle in, hold on and wait for about one minute, 
finally,[image] you may slowly pull it out.

Comment: It worked for me!

Comment: I've done this on two occasions now. The flame-heated needle is much less risky that the superglue approach and it works quickly and incredibly well. I've done it only with the harder "pen" style nib although it appears that this one is much more likely to break off than the pencil style one.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me this morning, but I successfully got it out. What I did was take a thin bobby pin and ran the tip of it along a rough piece of metal in one direction over and over till I bent the very tip into a tiny hook. Then I inserted it into the stylus to the side of the latch mechanism's opening. I made the sure the hook was facing the broken plastic tip and I carefully barely ran it back and forth and pressing against the plastic to make a small groove so I could try pulling it out. I had to try it a few times and it didn't seem like it was working till I took another look inside and realized it popped out at some point during the process. I don't know how far back the coils for the active digitizer is, so don't go too far back; just enough to tough the broken plastic tip. Hope this works for you or anyone else reading this!

Answer (score 3):

I just did this. All it took was a pin (I used a safety pin, because it's easier to get a grip). I jabbed it into the top of the tip HARD and then slowly pulled up. The tip came right out, first try.

Comment: Good for you then. I was never able to jab a pin into the (pen-like) tip. Maybe it would be easier with the pencil-like tip.

Answer (score 3):

Superglue works well! I've tried the needle heating method but the needle just couldn't pull out the broken part even though it's already penetrated half of the tip. So I applied a little glue on the surface of the needle then stick into the hole and waited for about 2 min to pull the whole thing out~
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just pulled it out in a cheap (2 bucks), simple (2 mins), and physical (portable) way!

Steps:
 1. Go Amazon and search "beauty needle" (I got one from my hero mom!)
 2. Get a cheap needle like this:
[image]
 3. Insert the needle, hook the tip, and slowly pull outward, along the gap:
[image]
 4. Gently repeat step 3 until the two buckles around the tip become loose.
 5. Shake the tip out! Don't forget to tighten the two buckles a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to pull it out using a heated injection needle. You have to be quick and try to penetrate the plastic as fast as possible after the heating. Also wait at least a minute or two before pulling out.

Answer (score 0):

Use Safety pin and press it from one side and try to press niddle somewhat inside the pen, then slowly move your hand in pulling condition ( same why how we use spoon to take frozen icecream bite :) ). It works for me. Try it for several time and still not worked then heat safety pin, and do same. (But, it may damage your pen look). Best of Luck! :) :) :)